No user data returned from the userinfo endpoint (google oauth)
I am trying to retrieve user data by using the received access token but am only getting the following data:
{
    "sub": "123",
    "picture": "https:lh3.googleusercontent.com/..."
}

In the documentation it states that you should get user data, but I am not seeing it.
Does someone know why?
This is my code:
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
GOOGLE_SECRET = os.getenv("GOOGLE_SECRET")
GOOGLE_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?"
GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?"
GOOGLE_SCOPE = "openid profile email"
GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8050/google-callback"

@server.route("/google-callback")
def google_callback_route():
    access_token = get_access_token(request.full_path,
                                    GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL,
                                    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                                    GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
                                    GOOGLE_SECRET
                                    )
    # todo: make call to userinfo endpoint
    return None

def get_access_token(url: str, token_url: str, client_id: str, redirect_uri, client_secret=None) -> str:
    """Calls the oauth server and gets the access token based on the code"""
    query_params = urlparse(url).query
    code = parse_qs(query_params)['code'][0]
    body = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "grant_type": AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri
    }

    if client_secret is not None:
        body['client_secret'] = client_secret

    response = requests.post(url=token_url, data=body)
    access_token = response.json()['access_token']
    return access_token

I get the access token and when I use postman to make a call to:
 https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo
 Authorization: Bearer <access-token>

{
    "sub": "123",
    "picture": "https:lh3.googleusercontent.com/..."
}

When I try to use the people api which I approach using this url: https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses.
I get the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "service": "people.googleapis.com",
                    "method": "google.people.v1.PeopleService.GetPerson"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


Edit:
After using the following scopes and enabling the people api in the google console I do get some data returned but I still don't see the email address. Does someone know why?
GOOGLE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

When I now make a call to https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses with my access token I receive the following:
{
    "resourceName": "people/123",
    "etag": "some-etag",
    "names": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "primary": true,
                "source": {
                    "type": "PROFILE",
                    "id": "123"
                },
                "sourcePrimary": true
            },
            "displayName": "John Doe",
            "familyName": "Doe",
            "givenName": "John",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "Doe, John",
            "unstructuredName": "John Doe"
        }
    ]
}

As you see there is no email address, I have no idea why.

Edit 2:
It did work but I accidentally used a cached version of my login screen. Which resulted in a call being made with the old scopes. After I CTRL-R'd the login screen it worked!

Google doesnt always return data from the userinfo endpoint they recomend using the People api.   I think you should check that access token and make sure it was created using the scopes you think it was.

That is exactly what the problem was (see Edit 2). I accidentally used a cached version of my login screen which resulted in an access token being created with incorrect scopes!

any reason your doing all this manually and not using the client library?

To practice and it felt kinda like overkill to add an import for this. But what do you recommend, to use a library? If so, which one?

Its easier to use the library.   I thought I was the only one who did it myself to learn.   Welcome to the club
